# How to share drives with Docker Linux containers in Azure Web Apps for Containers?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I am deploying a Linux container onto the Azure Web Apps for Containers and getting errors as I do so:

```
2019-05-22T18:33:20.506771506Z       Unable to start Kestrel.
2019-05-22T18:33:20.506777506Z Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file
2019-05-22T18:33:20.520011951Z    at Interop.Crypto.CheckValidOpenSslHandle(SafeHandle handle)
2019-05-22T18:33:20.520078751Z    at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FromFile(String fileName, SafePasswordHandle password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
2019-05-22T18:33:20.536820007Z    at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
2019-05-22T18:33:20.536851707Z    at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName, String password)
2019-05-22T18:33:20.536857407Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.LoadCertificate(CertificateConfig certInfo, String endpointName)
2019-05-22T18:33:20.536862107Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.LoadDefaultCert(ConfigurationReader configReader)
2019-05-22T18:33:20.536866907Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.Load()
2019-05-22T18:33:20.536871307Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.ValidateOptions()
2019-05-22T18:33:20.536884408Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  myservice:
    image: myimage:latest-tag
    ports:
      - "5555"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/etc/ssl/certs/certificate.pfx
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=mypassword
    volumes:
      - C:\path\to\certs:/etc/ssl/certs

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat
```

I created a new Web App for Containers instance, set it up using the above `docker-compose.yml` file and get the above error. I have seen this error before when attempting to `docker run` the app on my development environment. It is something to do with Docker attempting to access a shared drive on my computer. Docker Desktop will prompt me and ask if I want to share that drive and to input login credentials.

However, I do not know how to do this in Azure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is an external storage C:\path\to\certs and this is a path inside the container - /etc/ssl/certs. However,  C:\path\to\certs does not exist on our worker since its a Linux Machine and C:\ doesn't exit. So if you want to map the Persistent storage we provide we have to use ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}. Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/configure-custom-container#use-persistent-storage-in-docker-compose

Comment: This helped me. Thank you.